# Getting average number of an array , breaks if one of them is -1 on JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, for-loop, break

I'm resolving some problems given at college but I can´t figure out this one.
The exercise goes like this :

> Create a program where users enter numbers until they enter "-1", in this case, the program breaks and prints the average of the numbers entered.

I've written this on JS

```
array=[];
    for( var i =0; i<3; i++){
        val = parseInt(prompt( "Insert your numbers: "));
        array.push(val)
        }
function insert (array){
    var sum = 0;
    array.forEach(num=>{
        sum+= (num) / array.length;
    })
    return sum
}

console.log( "Average is " + Math.round(insert(array)))
```

I tried to write:

```
if (val == -1){
    breaks;
}
```

But it just breaks everything. I know maybe there is a simplier way to solve it and probably I'm still strugling with logic in loops. The thing is that the promps has to stop looping if the user inserts -1.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Approach looks correct however, there is not `breaks` keyword. It is [`break`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/break) and you have to use it inside the loop after `val = parseInt`

Comment: Thanks @SunilChaudhary, it solved the issue, [break] was well written, I just was placing it out of the loop. I gotta improve that logic, haha. Really thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
array = [];

while((val = parseInt(prompt( "Insert your numbers: ")))!=-1)
{
    array.push(val)
}
function avg (array){
    var sum = 0;
    array.forEach(num=>{
        sum += num;
    })
    return array.length ? sum / array.length : 0;
}

console.log( "Average is " + Math.round(avg(array)))
```

Comment: the thing is that until the users writes -1, it keeps looping. It should stop at some point to return the average number of previous inputs. Thanks anyway, I hadn't had in count I could use [while]

Comment: @Juliet, well that is the idea isnt it? User can stop at any time by typing "-1".

Answer (score 0):

```
let numbers = [];
let val, sum, result

askForInput();

function askForInput(){
   val = parseInt(prompt("Pls enter a number: "));
   if(val == (-1)){
      result = getAverage(numbers);
      console.log("Result is: " + result);
   } else {
      askForInput();
   }
}

function getAverage(array){
   if(array.length == 0) return 0;
   for(let i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
      sum += array[i];
   }
   return sum / array.length;
}
```

An example using recursion

Comment: thanks @rorychatt, I am a freshman on Js, your code got me into study of recursion. Very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

I would change the for loop to while so that the loop will only terminate if the user puts in -1 (the way you have it written currently, the for loop will terminate once the user has entered 3 numbers). If you initialize a variable before the while loop that changes to equal the user input, then you can even handle the logic in the loop definition.

EX:

```
array = []; 
user_input = 0;

while (user_input != -1 ) {
 user_input = parseInt(prompt( "Insert a number: "));
 array.push(user_input)
}
```

This code should continually prompt the user until they enter -1 at which point the while loop would stop.